# Redirect Existing Post to CPT

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect

I want to redirect the existing posts (nearly 2000) to a custom post type (say news) without interrupting newly created normal posts say (apps) after that, would that be possible?

Answer (score 0):

create a way to check the post date, and make a if statment

```php
if( $date_of_post < '2021-10-08') {
    header('Location:https://google.com');
    die();
}
```